# Finding error using %%cython extension in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, cython, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know any means that I can use to find errors in my cython code? I am using the cython extension for the IPython Notebook and its starting to get annoying having to scan through my code all the time looking for errors when all you have to work with is something like this:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-430-92c892360488> in <module>()
----> 1 knn_alg(temp, start, L, w, B)

C:\Users\Patrick\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_3cbae3230d887da1f1bc3c64de69c379.pyd in _cython_magic_3cbae3230d887da1f1bc3c64de69c379.knn_alg (C:\Users\Patrick\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_3cbae3230d887da1f1bc3c64de69c379.c:3333)()

C:\Users\Patrick\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_3cbae3230d887da1f1bc3c64de69c379.pyd in _cython_magic_3cbae3230d887da1f1bc3c64de69c379.knn_alg (C:\Users\Patrick\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_3cbae3230d887da1f1bc3c64de69c379.c:2534)()

ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 1)
```

I know what it means and what to look for but it would just be nice if it output something that shows you where the error is. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure what your error is without seeing more of your code.
That being said, it appears that the error is in line 1 of the cell you are evaluating after your Cython code.

What the error is saying is that you are passing a 1-D array to a function that is expecting a 2-D array.
It looks like this is happening in one of the function calls inside the function `knn_alg`.
Here's a minimum working example showing what you are doing wrong:

```
def break_things(double[:,:] a):
    pass
def break_inner_things(double[:] a):
    # Here you're passing a 1-D array to a function that expects a 2D array.
    break_things(a)
```

If you need more detailed debugging messages, Cython has a [debugger](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/debugging.html).
For something simple like this, I would just find a small example that still exhibits the error, then insert print statements to verify the number of dimensions of the things involved.
With the example above, this would be

```
def break_things(double[:,:] a):
    pass
def break_inner_things(double[:] a):
    print a.ndim
    break_things(a)
```

Comment: I understand what I am doing wrong its just there are a lot of variables that I am declaring and it would be much easier to be able to find the point where the code stops running to see what input is not corresponding with the buffer that I declared with the variable. That being said I'll have to take a look at that debugger. I hope it can run through ipython notebook.